# Are there any hyper-drive based Star Wars weapons?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, hyperspace

Are there any hyper-drive based Star Wars weapons? I would think rather than fancy missiles, you would just want to send an inexpensive, weaponized hyperdrive to blow up an enemy ship.

You would basically aim a hyperdrive at a course set *through* an enemy ship, and then let it fly.

There would be several benefits to using them:

1. They are traveling at relativistic speeds, giving them the most bang-for-their-buck.
2. They are fairly inexpensive, as there are already hyperdrives in many common space vehicles.
3. You wouldn't even be able to detect one until it hits you.

**So, are there any hyper-drive based Star Wars weapons?**

**If so, why aren't they more common, given the multiple benefits listed above?**

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/3vufas/star_wars_how_come_no_one_uses_hyperdrives_as/

Comment: I've always wondered why the rebels didn't just get a bunch of cheap ships with hyperdrives, put a remote control system in them, and then hyper-jump them into Star Destroyers...

Comment: It's not hyperdrive-_based_, but [Starkiller Base](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller_Base) "tear[s] a hole through hyperspace along a perfectly linear path. The people stationed at the Base called the dimension through which the phantom energy beam traveled "sub-hyperspace", and this method of delivering the payload was near-instantaneous across vast distances."

Comment: @RedCaio Good point. There is still a big difference between "instantaneous" and near-instantaneous though. You could watch the near-hyperspeed energy beam streaking through space, while you can't see spaceships traveling at hyperspace.

Comment: Does the [gravity well projector](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gravity_well_projector) from the original Thrawn trilogy count (at least I think they were in those books, maybe the two sequels to the original trilogy?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Dark Empire comics an Engineer named Umak Leth invented something called a Galaxy Gun, it launched missiles into hyperspace. It was used several times to destroy planets in far away systems and the Emperor attempted to use it to destroy the Rebel fleet.

[image]
[image]
*Images from Dark Empire II #5*

Comment: Sounds very similar to the energy beams from Starkiller Base in *The Force Awakens*.  Shot through hyperspace to distance plants.

Comment: Do you have any idea why straight-up hyperdrive missiles aren't more common?

Comment: @JoshB.- Well, this is Legends now. In canon, it’s not at all clear *how* dangerous a hyperdrive weapon is in canon. Reverting to realspace from hyperspace near a massive body can do a lot of damage, but how much is unknown. Hitting a massive body while in hyperspace is probably impossible, since the gravity well will drag you out (and quite likely evaporate you, according to *Aftermath*: how much damage that would do to the nearby planet is unclear).

Comment: **Update** The Last Jedi...