# Could you destroy the Death Star by having a ship come out of hyperspace in the middle of it?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, death-star, hyperspace

So the Death Star is huge, right? Would it be possible to coordinate a hyperdrive to come out of hyperspace in the middle of the Death Star?

Maybe a small ship wouldn't be enough to destroy it,  but let's say it was something the size of the Home One?  Or maybe some sort of crazy explosive device inside a smaller ship.

As for the pilot, I'm thinking maybe it could be done by remote control? Or a kamikaze pilot willing to sacrifice himself to take out the Empire's worst weapon.  But I like remote control better.

Could this plan work?  And whether yes or no,  why?

To clarify, I may not be understanding hyperspace correctly, but I'm not talking about crashing into it from the *outside*. I am suggesting you [exit hyperspace](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138311/64504) so that you appear in the *middle* of the Death Star.

<sup>Related: [What happens if two ships come out of hyperspace at the exact same time and place?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138223/64504)</sup>

Comment: Some possible answers [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-didnt-the-rebels-just-blow-up-the-Death-Star-by-going-Kamikaze-at-lightspeed), though someone would have to research to find specific sources to back them up.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'd end your trip real quick.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115994/are-there-any-hyper-drive-based-star-wars-weapons

Comment: Why not strap a hyper drive onto a big phallic shaped piece of metal, stick in nav computer and everything and you have a weapon that travel faster than light speed and can attack anything in the galaxy in a short amount of time. This would potentially be much more effective than the death star's super laser, and could be fired from much smaller ships. The weapon could be as small as the smallest hyperdrive. Even an object the size of the falcon (which has a very fast hyperdrive), would cause huge destruction at relativistic speeds, maybe, if the physics wasn't so messy.

Comment: @JoshB. Sorry, I should have read your link before commenting, but that is a very good question. Out of universe, it may have been too OP, or just no one thought of it I suppose.

Comment: @chewie No worries, I agree that it would probably be too OP.

Comment: Because you can't travel in hyperspace through solid objects.

Comment: @LordSalizar I know I'm probably missing something  but I'm still not sure. I have asked others: From Wookiepedia: "jumping" from a specific point to another point without having to travel directly between them."

Comment: @LordSalizar Welp.... not to revive an old post... but have you seen the last Jedi yet? HyperSpace Collision seem to be super effective. Why the hell did they build a death star in the first place?

Comment: I don't think that was a hyperspace collision at all.  SW plays fast and loose with physics, but the assumption of all objections I've seen is that this was a (universe breaking) relativistic event. With some math, you find a Raddus-sized ship going even .00025c would generate a blast completely engulfing the Supremacy. So if you are trying for consistent physics, then either hyper-collisions obey some very different rules or that was not one. More details: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176287/why-was-the-holdo-manoeuvre-not-used-earlier#comment478941_176837

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The (canon) Star Wars novel [*Tarkin*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel)) would suggest that a capital ship reverting to realspace near to a large static body could do very severe damage.

> Despite being crewed by sentients, the mysterious cruiser hadn’t
>   discharged any of its point-defense or ranged weapons. **If destruction
>   of the base was the goal, why hadn’t whoever was behind the attack
>   used the ship as a bomb by reverting from hyperspace in closer
>   proximity to the moon? Planetary bodies larger than Sentinel had been
>   shaken to their core by such events.**

Note that hitting a large object ***within hyperspace*** or reverting inside it isn't really an option. Planetary gravity fields (and those generated by large space stations) are sufficient to drag a ship out of hyperspace. At best you could hit it at high speed.

---

That all being said, the Death Star has a large and highly efficient shield. It isn't until considerable damage is done to the core (and presumably the shield generator loses power) that it becomes vulnerable to a physical impact so unless you expect to find the shield down, ploughing into it at any speed is pretty worthless.

Comment: Considering Pablo Hidalgo’s recent comment on hyperspace within a gravitation field, and the related examples, perhaps the part about being dragged out of hyperspace is worth mentioning?

Comment: Though I do think that hitting an object *not* within hyperspace with an object within hyperspace *is* essentially impossible.

Comment: @Adamant Until _The Last Jedi_ was released I guess.

Comment: @StevenRands - I would imagine that the Resistance didn't have anything big enough to make the impact worthwhile.

Comment: In TFA didn’t they penetrate the shields of Starkiller Base by hyperspacing through them, making the last paragraph moot?

Comment: @Darren - They approached them at a high enough speed that the ship was able to pass through the shield during its normal power cycle. If they'd been unlucky,  they'd have slammed into the shield and died. Note that this cycling on and off only applies to planetary shields, not ship shields.

Answer (score 6):

### It'll be extremely difficult to hit

Death Star is not still. Although it seems like a planet or a moon orbiting, it's a battle station that keeps in movement. It's displacement and speed out of hyperspace is so slow related to other ships that it seems to be still, but it isn't.

Calculate the exact coordinates where it will be in the moment the hyperspace jump is astronavigated is more difficult that it could seems. Keep in mind that space is HUGE, hit it knowing it's exact position would be difficult enough, but possible due to it's size.

But even if you make the hit and impact it

### It's too big to get destroyed by a collision

Even Star Destroyers are tiny in comparison with Death Star size. You'd probably able to initiate a chain reaction enough powerful to destroy it if you manage to impact one of the critical points of the ship (AKA 'the reactor'), but this is almost impossible because your ship won't teleportate to the inside of the Death Star, it just will crash into the surface at light speed.

Wich makes me state that

### Physics gets complicated when you add light speed to the mix

Real physics are more complicated than basic kinetic. When you add speed of light to anything, the usual side effect is everything becoming plasma and any small impact becoming nuclear and potentially capable to destroy a planet (even if you just use a [baseball](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/))

However, real physics and hyperspace jump are things that doesn't mix quite good, it will be a bit hypocritical to state that the kamikaze vessel will became a mix of unstable protons able to hit the Death Star with the strength of one thousand nuclear bombs without stating that it'd probably disintegrate in the first miles of hyper jump.

So

### Trying to Keeping It Simple

If we adhere to a simplistic physics model, even throwing a Star Destroyer at it wouldn't be probably enough to destroy it (well... maybe a Star Destroyer could make *enough* damage with the crash) due to the relative differences in size.

And that's if you manage to hit it, in the first place.

### EDIT:

From [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hyperspace/Legends)

Hazards of Hypertravel:
"Hyperspace collisions, whether they be intentional or by accident, could devastate or even destroy a planet. Considering the fact that the output of the reactors of many Capital ships rivaled or eclipsed that of a star, and that the energies needed to make hyperspace travel possible were vast, one could unleash a great deal of destructive power on a target. Even if a planet had its planetary shielding up at the time of a hyperspace collision, it could still have the potential to kill millions on a world such as Coruscant just due to the fallout. One of the more famous hyperspace accidents occurred during the Clone Wars, when the battlecruiser Quaestor collided with the Separatist planet Pammant, fracturing it to its core."

**So I supose we, in the end, can accept that ramming with a ship enough big into the Death Star will be able to destroy it.**

Comment: I may not be understanding hyperspace correctly, but why does it imply crashing into it from the outside? I was thinking you *exit* hyperspace so that you *appear* in the middle of the Death Star.

Comment: Hyperspace is not a teleportation it's travel at very high speed. Astronavigation has to be made prior to a jump to avoid crashing into planets, stars, blackholes. You also can crash into a space vessel or a tiny asteroid (which, obviously won't be able on the navigation charts), but the odds are infinitesimal

Comment: What about hyperspace jumps? Isn't that like teleportation?

Comment: Not in SW universe

Comment: From Wookiepedia: "jumping" from a specific point to another point without having to travel directly between them."

Comment: Even assuming that (which I ever thought it's different), hit to a "vulnerable" part of the station, even knowing the location and the vessel internal plans, would be extremely difficult. If you don't hit a sensible spot, the impact effect is only a bit more damaging that if you hit the surface.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperspace/Legends "Hyperspace was an alternate dimension of space-time, similar to subspace or otherspace,[2] that was coterminous with realspace: each point in realspace was associated with a unique point in hyperspace. Essentially, a ship travelling galactic north in realspace as it jumped to hyperspace would travel north in hyperspace too. Every object in realspace, like stars or planets, also had a "shadow" in hyperspace at the same location it occupied in realspace." This explains that, in fact, you'll crash the Death Star Hyperspace shadow's surface.

Comment: Makes sense, but what if you were making a jump rather than traveling directly through hyperspace?

Comment: cant be done, move along. every object has a shadow in hyperspace. a nav computer detecting an object will in most instances drop you out of hyperspace intentionally to avoid such collisions. now if you are a suicide bomber you could prob hack the nav computer to disregard the safety protocols. in this instance you crash into the side of another object. there is no teleportation, jumps, blinks or anything else of the sort in SW universe. You would have to be EXTREMLY lucky to even get that done as the Death Star isn't a stationary object, it moves so Bardo has the correct answer.

Comment: The station may be moving, but you don't have to come from across the galaxy. Say you are a few miles away, and are being tractor beamed into it. Do a hyperspace jump for a few miles, you'll know exactly where it will be. Suicide, but still. While at it, can hyperspace break a tractor beam. Guess thats a different question.

Comment: RoTJ shows a Super Star Destroyer crashing into the death star with pretty much no effect on the operational status of the station

Comment: Another possibility is that the Death Star had [gravity well projectors](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_well_projector) which have been shown to be able to pull ships out of hyperspace, so that any ship approaching its location in hyperspace would be yanked out before it could collide.

Comment: @Cherubel I don't know much about this, but the Wookiepedia article on hyperspace says "jumping" in hyperspace is possible?

Comment: By the way, to everybody: I'm not trying to argue with the answer or anything. I really don't mean to say that this is possible or anything. I'm just trying to understand it better. @NKCampbell

Comment: I have asked [another question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138311/64504) to try and clear up the part about jumping.

Comment: In ANH , Han talks about the necessity of plotting a path for a hyperspace jump, to avoid slamming into a star or something at light-speed. It's not teleportation.

Comment: @Fiksdal you are just fixated on the jumping word. it is a word to describe hoping from A to B. if there is something in that line the hyperdrive will pul you out of hyperspace as this is a built in feature. it is not possible to apear inside solid objects in SW using hyperdrives.

Comment: @DanShaffer Suposedly you cannot hyperdrive from a tractor beam, otherwise no one would be captured by it, as it could hyperjump away from the beam. I supose that a tractor beam have a ionic component that nullifies target ship's controls.

Comment: @Cherubel Alright, thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd always been under the impression that only the object in hyperspace would be destroyed. That was our West End Game rules, fwiw. If hyperdrive was an effective weapon, who needs a death star?

Comment: Welcome to Sci-Fi and Fantasy Stack Exchange. This is not an answer to the question, it is purely your opinion. Please follow the sites answering guidelines. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Interesting. This would be a good thing to post as a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Details from the SW universe are not always consistent with other statements from other SW sources, or thought out from a particular theory of how the science might work.  We can reconcile what we can, but may have to accept that some things contradict and must be regarded as inaccurate, waved away, or just anomalies.

I think the best explanation for hyperspace is some form of travel beyond our typical 4 dimensions.  You might consider it some form of worm hole theory, tunneling through space, or "wrinkling" space.

Any of those explanations actually would not necessarily result in the objects traveling in hyperspace to ever reach anywhere near relativistic speeds -- in the sense of the normal-space kinetic energy that would imply.

Entering this extra-dimensional space wouldn't, therefore imply even approaching the speed of light, kinetically.  Neither would exiting.  I would note that ships that come out of hyperspace appear to practically slam to a stop.

So, I don't think you can assume the exiting hyperspace would give any object sufficient kinetic energy to any special amount of damage.  Given that, you'd have to either wave away as inaccurate the reports of exiting too close to planet.  Unless something having to do with the size or fluctuation of the extra-dimensional space can have some affect -- perhaps unpredictably (and not always).

Also, if you try to reconcile the difficulty of navigating hyperspace with the emptiness of real space, you may conclude that mass and gravity actually have a far larger impact in hyperspace, so that (unlike in realspace), zipping about in hyperspace is like trying to slip a needle through tons of clusters of close and powerful magnetic fields without it getting pulled where you don't want it.

If that's a fair analogy, then even removing any potential safeguards from a hyperdrive engine (which would presumably attempt to drop you out of hyperspace in advance of a collision), the mass itself may interact with hyperspace in such away that it pulls you back into real space at a certain proximity (not within), perhaps too close to react but still, given the non-relativistic speeds the vehicle is actually traveling, too slow for the impact to do much harm to a much larger body.

All this being said, while hyperdrives have been calculated to allow starships to cross space in the SW universe at effectively many millions of times faster than light, even sublight speeds are nothing to sneeze at, with incredible acceleration and capability of crossing solar systems very rapidly.  Those sublight speeds could allow a massive starship to be a very dangerous projectile even at velocities still much lower than the speed of light.

All of this must be made possible by some form of inertial damper, which effectively soaks kinetic energy somehow so that the passengers effectively feel little to no movement.  This technology, like artificial gravity and repulsor technology (opposing gravity very precisely), also has many implications.

If starships can have inertial dampers for passengers, why not to mitigate the impact of collisions?  Either way, you're soaking kinetic energy relative to an object.  Granted, if this were possible, given enough reaction time for calculations of said dampers, then collisions (such as the SSD into the Death Star II, or asteroid fields, or other ship collisions), would be potentially irrelevant.  However, I think, given those aforementioned sublight speeds, some form of external inertial damper probably would exist with the capability to at least reduce the impact significantly, and possibly proportionately (i.e., halving the impact kinetic energy, vs. just subtracting a certain amount).  Otherwise collisions could still be crazy lethal.  Perhaps that's part of shielding?

It would help explain, however, why only energy weapons really matter in SW.  Why rail guns can't just be expected to rip through hulls and shields.

In sum:

1. Ships coming out of hyperspace may not be traveling very fast and
   have non-relativistic kinetic energy.

   2. It may be impossible to exit hyperspace in or even extremely close to a sufficiently massive object (though still close enough
      for unavoidable collision)
   3. Inertial dampers or shields may make kinetic impacts significantly less destructive.

Comment: 1/2) Shields are effective against kinetic weapons.  They always have to lower the shields to get a vehicle through.  Same with projectiles.

http://vsbattles.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Matthew_Schroeder/Star_Wars:_Speed_of_Blasters

Blaster fire sometimes appears to be slower than light, but is indicated in other places to be light speed.  Battles are conducted at relativistic distances.  In ROTJ, the Rebel fleet appears to be about 2 light seconds from the Death Star when it fires.

Comment: 2/2) In TLJ,  the fleet is just outside effective range, and (sorry, just memory) that is about 4-5 light seconds.  Getting a mass up to even .25c would be almost impossible, but it would still make those transit times 8-20s.  A more realistic .001c (1000x faster than the fastest bullet) would mean times of half an hour to two hours.  You can just maneuver out of the way of that, even in the slowest ship.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I will add an answer with a little bit of knowledge from mostly non-canon (i think) reference - Star Wars Roleplaying Game called Edge of the Empire from Fantasy Flight Games. This is a roleplaying game (like Dungeons and Dragons) with lots of rulebooks and sources.

There the explanation for the Hyperspace is that the nature of hyperspace is still a mystery, but we can travel through another dimension in the same direction as in real space.

> "... Objects, especially large objects with powerful gravity like
>   planets and stars, cast a shadow in hyperspace, and thus they exist in
>   both planes at once."

And every hyperspace engine is being designed with safety in mind. That means there are many

> "...sensors and failsafes designed to drop the ship immediately into
>   realspace if it passes dangerously close to a gravity well or mass
>   shadow. Acciddents do happen; there are many documented cases of a
>   ship in hyperspace colliding with a planet or flying into the heart of
>   a star. This, obviously spells certain death for the entire starship
>   and anyone aboard. In certain, very rare cases, the starship can even
>   come out of hyperspace far too close to a planet´s surface and crash
>   and dangerous speeds. This could even do considerable damage if it has the misfortune of impacting a city..."
>   ~Edge of the Empire Rulebook

So based on that, I believe that jumping out of the hyperspace within the boundaries of Death star is practically impossible, if you don´t somehow tamper with your hyperdrive.

But even if you materialized within the death star, it seems that based on that description, it is much more deadly for the ship, than the object. In my head, I imagine this as follows: Ship tries to "materialize" within an object, but there are different atoms, so the whole sctructure somehow collides and breaks the ship appart so the atoms "fit" between those that are already there, meaning, that the ship would crumble to pieces and dust and not doing considerable damage at all. But that is only my theory. Other canonical sources suggest that it would, indeed cause mayhem.

In any case, Empire possessed [Interdictor Class Star Destroyers with gravity wells](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Interdictor-class_Star_Destroyer).
This gravity wells are powerful gravity generators that can basically pull ships out of the hyperspace. Could a Death star have a gravity well projector on its own to protect against such attacks? I believe it is plausible.

Anyway, the ship could still jump out (or be pulled out) from hyperspace just before the contact. Incredible speed (and maybe some explosives rigged in the cargo) could truly do some considerable damage, but you have to realise how big the Death star was. Even assuming that blast could penetrate its powerful shields, it would still take at least a few dozens of rigged capital ships to even scratch through the surface. The Death star was simply huge and well defensed against capital ships, torpedoes, lasers and explosions. The exhaust port was it´s biggest weakness because it destroyed the generator and created chain reaction. You wouldn´t do that with a hundred of hyperspace-rigged ships.

Comment: Do *not* cite the failsafes here. A good old fashioned $3 wrench could bypass them if you actually wanted to.