# What happens if the Death Star comes out of hyperspace in the middle of an asteroid field?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, hyperspace

As [a counter-question to this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138226/could-you-destroy-the-death-star-by-having-a-ship-come-out-of-hyperspace-in-the), I wonder what happens if the Death Star comes out of hyperspace in the middle of an asteroid field... Or in the middle of a space fleet? Would it be destroyed?

<sup>**Edit**: My main question purpose was originally to know what kind of hyperspace travel the Death Star performs, but since this was edited out, I created a [specific question for this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149337/how-does-the-death-star-travel-in-hyperspace). This secondary question is not a duplicate of the [question I previously linked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138226/could-you-destroy-the-death-star-by-having-a-ship-come-out-of-hyperspace-in-the), it is in fact the opposite of it. So in order to clarify it better I will add this:</sup>

When the Death Star comes out of the hyperspace, if its entire mass occupies, for instance a group of ships spread around part or the entirity of its area, would they just be pushed out by it, or would they still remain in that area and probably overlapsed by the Death Star mass?

Comment: I'm joining the duplicate VTC (though the target's answers are only Legends canon, not Disney canon). If you feel that the question is different from the other one, please clarify how and i'll reopen

Comment: What happens? You get **choked to death** is what happens.

Comment: Why wouldn't it have the same experience as the Millenium Falcon did? Asteroid fields and space fleets are mostly empty space, so most likely it would just get hit by a flurry of debris or blaster bolts.

Comment: I don't think there's anything official, so this is speculation, but it probably would only kill a few thousand people living on its surface.  Remember in ROTJ, Vader's flagship (19 km in length) smashes into the Death Star's surface and doesn't cause much damage.  So in terms of the fleet, you might get a few broken up areas, and that's about it.  For the asteroids, those can be truly massive, and if it hits a 500km asteroid that's probably gonna hurt.  But I suspect they've got really good maps to avoid those things.

Comment: Relativity. And I'm not even talking about Einstein's relativity. Even by Newton's mechanics, the Death Star slamming into an object is the exact same as an object slamming into the Death Star. Joining the duplicate VTC.

Answer (score 3):

The Death Star is designed to turn planets into debris, very similar to an asteroid field, so I would be inclined to think it has suitable defenses (ie: shields, surface turrets for point defense) to avoid damage from such.  The only reason the Falcon appeared in the middle of "an asteroid field" in ANH is because they *thought they were going to arrive at Alderaan,* but arrived shortly after its destruction by the Death Star.  So, the Death Star itself is clearly equipped to handle such environments.

As for appearing in the middle of a space fleet, the fact that the rebels have *actually thrown* entire space fleets at each of the Death Stars we see in the movies - and *still* needed to rely on getting to the reactor core via subterfuge to actually stop them - should give you an idea of how that would turn out.  The only difference in your scenario would be that the space fleet **isn't** expecting a moon size space station / superweapon to suddenly appear in their midst.

Comment: Death Star would never be endangered by planet's debris. A rock thrown by a huge explosion would at best move at 25m/s (or so I read), so a DS firing from (usually) several lightseconds away has days of safety. That said, it has incredibly powerful shields and thousands of turbolaser batteries

Comment: 25 km/s is plausible. 25 m/s is not.

Comment: @Buzz I probably made a typo. Even at 25km/s, it would take a day for the rocks to reach the Death Star