# How does the Death Star travel in hyperspace?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, ftl-drive, hyperspace

Is there any reference in Canon or Legends on how the hyperspace travel of the Death Star is performed?

Is it in anyway similar to the hyperspace travels performed by other starships in the Star Wars universe? Or is there another kind of ftl-drive I am not aware of?

I understand that a [gaming book speculated that there were hyperdrive thrusters on the Death Star surface](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17463/76381), but is this referenced anywhere else? As a more technical approach, how would a massive body like this would achieve integrity in a hyperspace jump? Would all of these supposed hyperdrive thrusters need to be synchronized before the jump in order for the entire Death Star jump?

Comment: come to that, how did it move in normal space?

Comment: If you scroll down on your link, there is an answer pertaining to new Disney canon.

Comment: @DaveJohnson thanks, missed the other answer: in a [Legends journal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Technical_Journal_%28Volume_Two%29) it is mentioned that there is a matrix that synchronizes all of the "hyperspace generators": `One hundred twenty-three individual hyperspace generators, tied into a single navigational matrix, were necessary to carry the Death Star beyond the speed of light.`.