# Why was the 'Holdo maneuver' not used earlier?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

This question is related to *The Last Jedi*. The maneuver that Vice Admiral Holdo performs towards the end of the film seems remarkably effective.

It seems that it would have worked pretty well much earlier, especially as two other ships were just allowed to run out of fuel and be destroyed.

It seems doing it earlier with different assets would have incurred less losses. Yet nobody seemed to consider it. Any in-universe reason why not?

Comment: People don’t seem to like spoilers (as per game of thrones) so I’ve hidden any possible chances, we can come back and touch them up later

Comment: Once they did that, there was no reason for the FO to hold back their TIE's and hunt down the remaining smaller ships and transporters.

Comment: Also philosophically, undeniable suicide missions are not the resistance's way. Every life matters. As Rose ponints out: *Don't fight the ones you hate, but save the ones you love*. Of course kamikaze happens sometimes, but these are mostly decisions by a single individual in a desparate moment. This is not part of the overall strategy.

Comment: More pertinently, why was a human required to remain on the ship to essentially pilot it in a straight line at presumably maximum speed? Surely the ship had an autopilot, or at worst a droid could have been used. There's no in-universe reason for her to stay on board, it's purely a plot device required so that she could perform her later destructive action.

Comment: @StevenRands a captain goes down with their ship, same reason the two captains of the ones that ran out of fuel stayed on theirs.

Comment: @Edlothiad that would have been a fine justification in itself, no need to play the 'someone must stay with the ship' card.
Also we've seen several times in the SW universe where they 'scan for life forms' so wouldn't they notice they blew up an empty cruiser?

Comment: Maybe they could leave the worst pilot they have to make a noble sacrifice rather than the Grand Mega Admiral?

Comment: It was awesome to see them actually do that maneuver in the movie! Here's a related question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115994/are-there-any-hyper-drive-based-star-wars-weapons

Comment: Exactly the question I just started to type :D

Comment: Perhaps the Flagship had all energy directed to engines and weapons, but none directed to particle shields

Comment: Not using it earlier when it's the last cruiser the resistance has makes sense. What doesn't is when they didn't do it in earlier episodes since hyperspace has also canonically be proven to go through shields. But that would cut episode 6 really short if they just rammed a cruiser in the death star without going to Endor. And it could definitely have worked if they aimed correctly.

Comment: @MooS I'm not sure this is the case. Both *Rebels* and *Rogue One* featured command-ship kamikazes, and the Rebellion and Resistance seem philosophically near-identical.

Comment: Maybe it's just that no one in the GFFA ever thought of it before.   /s

Comment: In a way, isn't this how Starkiller base works?  It supposedly fires through hyperspace.  Matter and energy are equivalent, and it had to swallow a star.  Maybe it's just shooting an energy/matter beam through planets at hyperspace velocities.

Comment: Hello @MooS my old nemesis.

Comment: I honestly think that the can only get around this if you invented some new kind of hyperdrive. It's in Legends at least that nobody knows exactly how hyperdrives work. Maybe they just found out.

But if you do that, then we should all be expecting some massive changes in how SW handles space combat now. Because after this, it'll just be long-range hyperspace kinetic torpedoes.

Comment: this was a stupid movie from beginning to end. they assassinated Luke Skywalker and destroyed Star Wars. I thought ep7 was great. I actually liked Han dying. Ep 8 deserves to be remade

Comment: -1 For ridiculous use of spoiler alerts.

Comment: There are many things in real life that people never thought to do before the first time they thought to do them. Some of them have been horrifically destructive. “Failures of imagination” comes to mind.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I know that this is an old question, but I looked through the answers and the comments here and I noticed that no one has yet mentioned any relevant information from the novelization (not even those posted since the novelization was published), which I think provides the most sufficient answer to this question; and since none of the extant answers have been accepted by the user who asked the question, I thought that I would make a contribution. (Given the length that this answer ended up being, I decided to provide a **TL;DR** version at the end for those who don't have the time for the long version.)

Let me start by providing some background information: I believe that it's worth noting that, during the evacuation, they were in the process of siphoning their reserve fuel and extracting other supplies for their escape, and implementing other important procedures, but this was all interrupted by the arrival of the First Order fleet.

In the novelization, Lieutenant Connix is speaking to protocol droid PZ-4CO, who alerts her of the incoming First Order fleet.  Connix then asks the droid what still needs to be done.

> **PZ-4CO:** Approximately thirty percent of the deep fuel reservoir remains to be siphoned... Scuttle procedure for mission-critical computers is incomplete.  And maintenance stocks are still being transferred from lower-level stores.
>
> ...
>
> **Flight Officer Jones:** There are still thirty pallets of cannon shells in C bunker.
>
> <sub><sup>*p.25; [Star Wars: The Last Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)* by Jason Fry</sup></sub>

It's also noted that the ships that came to evacuate the Resistance base on D'Qar were already low on fuel when they arrived, but the process of siphoning out their reservoirs would take too long to be of any use (PZ-4CO said that it would take approximately 90 minutes to fully complete the evacuation procedures).  Connix gave an order to siphon what they could and be airborne in ten minutes.

The fact that they were in a hurry to finish the evacuation was also hinted at in the film (much more briefly) during the opening scene:

> **Resistance Evacuation Officer:** We're not clear yet. There are still 30 pallets of cannon shells in C bunker.
>
> **Lieutenant Connix:** Forget the munitions, there's no time. Just get everyone on the transports.
>
> [Star Destroyers appear]
>
> **Lieutenant Connix:** Oh, no.

Which is why later, shortly after leaving hyperspace when they realized that the First Order had somehow followed them, they were too low on fuel to risk making another hyperspace jump, a move which would have exhausted their remaining supply at the time.

The fact that their evacuation procedures were interrupted, and the fact that they were caught off-guard by the sudden reappearance of the First Order fleet, meant that they were ill-prepared for this situation and that their only viable option at the time was to attempt to outrun them for as long as possible at sub-light speeds.  In doing this, it was only a matter of time before each of the Resistance ships ran out of fuel, and their best chances for survival was to transfer survivors to the [*Raddus*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Raddus_(MC85_Star_Cruiser)) (which had the most fuel) from the other ships before they ran out.

Assuming that the kamikaze attack was a move that anyone considered early on, it most certainly wasn't an option until the ship making the maneuver was empty of all survivors (other than the pilot), as it would obviously be fatal for everyone on board.  And it appeared that the two smaller surviving ships, the [*Ninka*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ninka) and the [*Anodyne*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anodyne_(Nebulon-C)) (the [*Vigil*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vigil_(ship)) was destroyed in the battle that came immediately after the First Order coming out of hyperspace to chase the Resistance fleet), ran out of fuel shortly after evacuating, so it was likely never an option for either of them to pull it off.  In fact, it's entirely possible that the *Ninka* and *Anodyne* were already too low on fuel to even attempt this move by the time they started to evacuate their survivors over to the *Raddus.*

So, if this maneuver was ever considered prior to their arrival at Crait, the *Raddus* was likely the only ship that could pull it off successfully just based on how much fuel they all had.  As we saw in the film, despite trying to outrun the First Order for many hours, the *Raddus* still had enough fuel to make one last jump (and the plan was originally for Holdo to simply lead the First Order away from Crait, rather than attempt to make a counterattack).  The film indicates that her kamikaze attack was likely a last-ditch effort that she came up with on the fly shortly after she realized that their escape plan had been compromised.  This is confirmed in the novelization:

> Aboard the *Raddus*, a stunned Holdo could only watch as another transport exploded.
>
> ...
>
> Holdo choked back a dismayed cry.  She had to do something.  But what?  There was no way the *Raddus* could defend the transports -- they had moved beyond the protection of its shields.
>
> She looked helplessly at her console, searching for some answer that eluded her.  There was nothing.
>
> A light blinked on the interface with the navicomputer.
>
> Holdo called up the interface to dismiss whatever the alert was -- it would only distract her while she tried to think -- then paused.
>
> Someone had entered hyperspace coordinates into the system, calculating a jump that had never been made.  The navicomputer was asking if the coordinates should be purged.
>
> It was Dameron, she realized -- he'd rushed to the bridge as part of the plan he'd concocted, the one she'd correctly dismissed as too reckless and desperate to succeed.
>
> Holdo called the coordinates up on her console.  The Mon Calamari cruiser had kept traveling along its heading for Crait since the coordinates had been entered into the navicomputer.  As a result, the entry point for the hyperspace jump Poe had calculated was now behind the *Raddus*, on the other side of the First Order fleet.
>
> Holdo stared at her screen, trying to figure out what she had missed and concluded that her wild hope might not be completely unfounded.
>
> <sub><sup>*p.231-232; [Star Wars: The Last Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)* by Jason Fry</sup></sub>

Further, the novelization indicates that Holdo could not actually rush the maneuver, and had to pace her moves carefully and time it right in order for it to succeed:

> Aboard the *Raddus*, Holdo hastily rechecked that the heavy cruiser's navicomputer hasn't kicked back the overrides that she'd had to program into it.
>
> ...
>
> The First Order flagship began to slide across space ahead of the *Raddus*... Turbolaser fire continued to lance out from its bow, destroying the Resistance transports seekng safety on Crait.
>
> Holdo reminded herself that there was only one way to help the evacuees -- if she attracted the First Order's attention too early, her desperate gambit would come to nothing.  The only thing she could do was wait.
>
> <sub><sup>*p.247; [Star Wars: The Last Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)* by Jason Fry</sup></sub>

She got the time that she needed.  The First Order officers observing the situation noticed that the *Raddus* was turning.  First Order officer Captain Peavey considered the possibility that she may have been trying to stage a counterattack, but didn't consider the ship to be a threat, as the *Raddus*'s weaponry wasn't strong enough to damage the *Supremacy*. They quickly realized that she was actually preparing to jump to hyperspace; but, like General Hux, they dismissed it as just a futile attempt to distract them from the escaping transports.  They initially decided to let it make the jump to hyperspace, figuring that they could take care of it later (and the *Raddus* was still far enough away to be out of the effective range of the *Supremacy*'s cannons against its shields).  Both the novelization and the film show that Hux and the other officers didn't realize their grave mistake until it was too late.

And here's where arguably the key aspect to Holdo's gambit being successful comes into play: that being the *Raddus*'s experimental shields:

> The *Raddus*' key strength is its advanced deflector shield system that can push the envelope of protective energy far from its hull.
>
> <sub><sup>*p.10; [Star Wars: The Last Jedi: The Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary)*</sup></sub>

This is also mentioned in the *Incredible Cross-Sections* book for *The Last Jedi*:

> **Raised Shields:** The advanced deflector shields that cocoon the *Raddus* are an experimental design, capable of sustaining huge amounts of damage before failing.  Though the heavy pummeling by the First Order makes structural damage inevitable, most other ships would have been destroyed long before this point.
>
> <sub><sup>*p.8; [Star Wars: The Last Jedi: Incredible Cross Sections](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Incredible_Cross-Sections)*</sup></sub>

(Lest anyone think that this was a retcon done to explain "plot holes" or to deflect criticism of the film, the *Incredible Cross-Sections* book and *The Visual Dictionary* for *The Last Jedi* were both published on December 15, 2017, the same day as the film's release.)

These shields played a crucial role in how effective and devastating the lightspeed ramming ended up being against the *Supremacy*.

> When the heavy cruiser plowed into the *Supremacy*'s broad flying wing, the force of the impact was at least three orders of magnitude greater than anything the *Raddus*'s inertial dampeners were rated to handle.  The protective field they generated failed immediately, but the heavy cruiser's augmented experimental shields remained intact for a moment longer before the unimaginable force of the impact converted the *Raddus* into a column of plasma that consumed itself.
>
> However, the *Raddus* had also accelerated to nearly the speed of light at the point of that catastrophic impact -- and the column of plasma it became was hotter than a sun and intensely magnetized.  This plasma was then hurled into hyperspace along a tunnel opened by the null quantum-field generator -- a tunnel that collapsed as quickly as it had been opened.
>
> Both the column of plasma and the hyperspace tunnel were gone in far less than an eyeblink, but that was long enough to rip through the *Supremacy*'s hull from bow to stern, tear a ragged hole in a string of Star Destroyers flying in formation with it, and finally wink out of existence in empty space thousands of kilometers beyond the First Order task force.
>
> <sub><sup>*p.251-252; [Star Wars: The Last Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)* by Jason Fry</sup></sub>

**TL;DR**

Given the desperate situation that they were in, which was already bad from the start and was only getting worse by the minute, it's unlikely that anyone ever considered this move earlier in the events of the film.  In fact, I was unable to find any information that indicates that anyone *had* considered trying this move prior to the moment that Holdo executes it, and that she only came up with it on the fly when it became clear that their escape plan had been compromised; and even if anyone did consider it prior to that point, it simply wasn't an option until any vessel that would have been used for this purpose had at least been evacuated (and even then, it still would have needed enough fuel to execute a hyperspace jump, which the *Ninka* and *Anodyne* clearly lacked compared to the *Raddus*).  **And ultimately, thanks to its advanced experimental deflector shields**, the *Raddus* was the only ship in the Resistance fleet that *could* have been used to execute this move and achieve the results that we witnessed on film.

Executing this move earlier simply wasn't an option.

Comment: Experimental shields did it. Thanks

Comment: Of course, this suggests the development of "Holdo-class" capital ship missiles - robotic ships with new shield, hyperspace engine and enough fuel for one short jump, and nothing else. Carried as parasites within the shield of the host ship.

Answer (score 34):

From the official [Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/hyperdrive):

> Hyperdrives allow starships to travel faster than the speed of light, crossing space through the alternate dimension of hyperspace. Large objects in normal space cast “mass shadows” in hyperspace, so hyperspace jumps must be precisely calculated to avoid collisions

**Apparently, this maneuver works, but only if you are jumping a massive object.**

It is hard to tell how massive something has to be for that to work, but we can chalk it up to plot that the lost ships wouldn't have been massive enough.

In terms of war economy it is easy to see why this tactic isn't widely used by a smaller force as well(as is the case with the Resistance). In terms of battle economy, if you keep throwing big, expensive ships like that at your enemy, you might be able to cause more damage than your ship is worth, but that still doesn't mean you will be able to cause more damage than the ship is worth *to you*. In such a small force, the loss of a cruiser might be devastating, therefore it might only be thought as an strategy in last resort. This is the basis of utility theory in economy.

In regards to war economy that would have made more sense if done much earlier, as instead of losing 3 ships, they would just have lost the bigger one. But that still wouldn't be a guarantee win, since destroying the Supremacy clearly didn't stop the First Order from attacking Crait, and it might have even pushed the First Order into a fiercer attack.

Remember that the First Order only continued this starvation tactic because they believed the rebels had no escape, and maintaining this tactic would be more efficient than losing more fighters on a long range engagement. By poking it's big ship, they would be risking enraging the quiet lion into an attack.

**Edit:** A lot of people keep pointing out that the "mass shadows" are cast by the massive objects in realspace, not by the one in hyperspace, and that is true. Still, we can take two things from this:

- First, this proves that collisions can indeed occur in hyperspace,
  and it is plausible to assume that the Supremacy is big enough for
  that to happen.
- Second, we know that an object in hyperspace interacts
  with the "mass shadow" of an object in realspace, not directly to the
  object itself.

In my mind this means that when collisions occur, the velocity of impact isn't really as important as the mass of the object, since any damage we are doing here isn't  damage "to the actual realspace structures" but more like gravitational damage dealt by our ships mass interacting with this "mass shadow". This would be either by stripping mass shadow away or (as the effect in the movie makes more likely) stripping bits of mass *into* hyperspace.

This last paragraph is just my theory, and there is no source anywhere that corroborates how a hyperspace collision would happen, as far as we know this is the first time something like this ever took place in canon(thought the bit on mass shadows proves it is possible).

It might seem that I am trying too hard to explain why smaller ships can't do this maneuver, and it is because I am. The size restriction is the only explanation that would afford this tactic not being worth using and therefore it not being established previously.

Comment: I think you’ve misread it, it says large objects in normal space cast “mass shadows” in hyperspace, so jumps have to be calculated for other ships to avoid those shadows (snokes ship being bigger than anything before would make sense)

Comment: Mind providing a link to the Database?

Comment: @Edlothiad You are indeed right, but what I keep thinking is that the mass of the objected jumped must be relevant as well. I have no way to prove this, so I do not know how to change the answer, but knowing how these "mass shadows" work, I doubt a smaller ship would have enough mass to displace a much much bigger one. Only by jumping two ships or comparative mass would have caused any damage.

So I accept suggestions on how to better this answer.

Comment: Not sure this argument makes sense. If we're talking about people routinely using this tactic, they wouldn't be using 'big expensive ships' they would be using big, cheap ships. As in, strap sublight + hyperspace engines to an asteroid level of cheap. No need to build hull, life support, weapons or shields.

Comment: @Scott this seems to be against the whole Star Wars ethos. In real life, mass drives are a thing. A tungsten pebble propelled near the speed of light would probably be about as devastating as a few nuclear bombs(which we haven't seen either in movies). Yet, in Star Wars they seem to be against this tactic, and I'm not sure why. I mean, they have [mass driver technology](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mass-driver_cannon/Canon)(though the one in the link is more akin to a railgun), it just seems nobody ever explained the creators the effectiveness of the tech in space warfare.

Comment: Another thing that might come into play is how counterable such a move could be. The First Order knew that Holdo was firing up Light Speed, but completely ignored her. If they hadn't the Resistance would have still won a few crucial minutes to reach the planet, but the light speed suicide run might have missed.

Comment: @Edelk I thought about that as well, but considering how much time the rear shields held, it is pretty safe to assume that it would still hold for the amount of time for them to turn the ship around. The only other thing to consider in that case would be range, as the rebel ship probably only survived because it was out of range of the Supremacy's main weapons and fighters. Turning the ship would mean the Supremacy could have enough time to catch up and fire a stronger barrage at them, completely overloading their shields.

Comment: Wrong answer, large objects that cast mast shadows are planets or stars. Not the ship doing jump itself. Mass shadows are shadows from realspace to hyperspace, not vice versa . And when object is pulled from hyperspace to realspace, it does not travel at light speed .

Comment: What @Edlothiad said.  This answer interprets the quote backwards.  What it says is that a massive object floating about in normal space will create a "mass shadow" in hyperspace that any ship traveling through hyperspace (regardless of size/mass) must avoid.  Which means you need a _big_ target.  Precisely how big is unclear, but in the original movies Han mentions that planets can interfere with hyperspace jumps, so anything planet-massed and up is an issue.  Probably the real threshold is somewhat less than that, as Snoke's ship, while very large,  is likely smaller than a planet.

Comment: @Edelk - Not necessarily.  Depending upon the sophistication of your sensors, the distance of the engagement, and whether or not hyperspace travel actually exceeds the speed of light through normal space, it's possible that the impact from a hyperspace kamikaze run would arrive prior to any of the light from the attacking ship.  Which would make the attack very difficult to counter/evade.  Unless you just _constantly_ fly in a random/erratic pattern to make your path impossible for an attacker to predict.

Comment: @aroth, First, I made an edit to clarify this point. I am not considering moving this clarification to the top of the answer, since I do not want to spread more misinformation, but as I explain there, the mass of the jumping ship being important is the only possible explanation for why this tactic isn't used more often by smaller, desperate forces. Second, on your following comment, such tactics would be unnecessary, since ships can detect when others are preparing to jump to hyperspace and they can see where they are pointing. In this case it was just a matter of not paying attention.

Comment: Even with economy of ships considered, that doesn't explain why in ANH the Rebellion didn't go launch a couple of cruisers at the Death Star to guarantee its destruction.  A couple of ships seems a small price to pay vs. total annihilation, especially when the alternative attacking strategy doesn't have a good guarantee of success.

Comment: "Traveling through hyperspace ain't like dusting crops, boy! Without precise calculations we could fly right through a star or bounce too close to a supernova and that'd end your trip real quick, wouldn't it?" - Han Solo ANH. I always took that to mean it is possible to run into stuff while in hyperspace.

Comment: @Kapler a strong gravitational field (e.g. a star) can somehow interfere with hyperspace travel and pull a ship back into normal space. If that happens too close to a star, you're toast.

Comment: @Joshua My guess is that the Death Star - having gravitational field generators - cannot be rammed via hyperdrive acceleration, because ships can't go into hyperspace near gravity fields. Starships usually don't have these but could outmaneuver a ship aiming for them - except if they are too bulky. So Snokes fault would have been NOT to integrate gravity field generators on his flag ship.

Comment: @Adwaenyth, your comment has me curious now.  What qualifies as a "gravity field" in the Star Wars universe?  We see ships go into hyperspace in gravity fields all the time (in orbits around planets, etc.).  In fact, the whole universe is technically embedded in a gravity field from all the mass in the universe.  Not a criticism of your comment, just curious how this is resolved in-universe.

Comment: @Joshua EU/Legends stuff mostly, but strong gravity wells require ships to get to a certain distance or they are unable to enter or stay in hyperspace. If you take the real life version of gravity, it falls off with the square of the distance, thus getting out a few thousand km more will let you enter while any closer and you can't. Some ships and the Death Stars are equipped with gravity well generators so that they create such a strong field around them that ships can't stay within hyperspace. If you place that on a common hyperspace lane, every ship gets pulled out of hyperspace there.

Comment: Well and again, everyone, it comes down to logic. The rebels can't afford to just keep launching expensive cruisers at Order ships. Who knows if the planet that built those cruisers can even build more? Those cruisers are precious assets, so to just keep launching them like giant missles at Order ships, when the Order can just go build another one and replace it, whereas Leia's rebels cannot.............seems illogical to do this maneuver unless it was a dire straights situation like it was for Holdo when she did this. It took some of the heat off, but they knew there was still a fight ahead.

Comment: While kamikaze isn't the rebel's way that doesn't mean it wouldn't be used.  Soldiers who find themselves in a situation where survival is impossible are prone to at least try to take the enemy with them.  We have one documented US WWII kamikaze--his plane was damaged, he couldn't hope to get home, if he jumped the only possible rescue would be from the very fleet he was bombing.  I would expect a ship that couldn't escape it's pursuers and expected death rather than capture would try to ram.

Comment: @Althis this does not add up:  "if you keep throwing big, expensive ships like that at your enemy, you might be able to cause more damage than your ship is worth, but that still doesn't mean you will be able to cause more damage than the ship is worth to you. "   This only argues that Kamikadze-like attacks make no sense. Sometimes the ship could be already damaged-this alters the economy. The enemy may be threatening a target more valuably than your ship, also they may be faster than you, forcing you to fight with them, and take potentially greater losses than a single ship.

Answer (score 32):

**Plot hole, somewhat bigger than usual ones** ;) Going lightspeed through enemy ships would be perfect tactics e.g. for droids in the Clone Wars. Expendable, programmable pilots that could kamikaze cheap ships into enemy capital vessels.

Why didn't they do it? It was explicitly stated that ship entering hyperspace does not have physical contact with objects in realspace. Story of Rogue One and some episodes in Rebels and Clone Wars are based exactly on this principle - ship goes into hyperspace very close to obstacle in realspace, but it is never touched. On the other hand, ships in realspace are slow (remember Hammerhead corvette in Rogue One), so ramming tactics are not that successful.

Comment: Can you back this up with anything? Quotes? Links? Sounds like rambling with a Disney rant at the end as-si

Comment: [Rogue](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/rogue) [Rouge](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/rouge)  Small difference in spelling, large difference in meaning.

Comment: This isn't so much a plot hole as opposed to a retcon. Your final statement is also a rant and does not benefit the answer in anyway.

Comment: @Machavity Did you watch Rouge One, Rebels or Clone Wars ? Or would link suffice ? :)  http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperspace

Comment: @Edlothiad If this isn't plot hole, then whole Clone Wars and original trilogy are . And final statement ... dreadful truth ... very dangerous thing in these turbulent times :)

Comment: @rs.29 It's called a retcon. I suggest you look up it's meaning ;). It doesn't matter if it's the "dreadful truth" or a blatant lie, it's opinionated and irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Edlothiad No, it is not retcon . Retcon is retroactive continuity . There is no continuity here. Rebels didn´t attack Death Star with small ships piloted by droids going lightspeed trough it. And, according to you they could. Nobody in entire history of SW got such bright idea. There is a reason for that.

Comment: @rs.29 sounds like a retcon to me "*(in a film, television series, or other fictional work) a piece of new information that imposes a different interpretation on previously described events, typically used to facilitate a dramatic plot shift or account for an inconsistency.*" and not like a plot hole: "*In fiction, a plot hole, plothole or plot error is a gap or inconsistency in a storyline that goes against the flow of logic established by the story's plot.*"

Comment: From the wiki: `However, large objects in realspace cast "mass shadows" in hyperspace, so hyperspace jumps necessitated very precise calculations.[3] Without those, a vessel could fly right through a star or another celestial body.[2]`

For those wondering what [2] is, it's Episode 4: A New Hope.

So no, objects in hyperspace are still solid, and can crash into things. This opens up two options in my mind, either hyperspace is related to mass, and you can only crash massive objects; or it is you really can crash into anything, and usually the drive only engages once it is safe.

Comment: @Althis First, it is celestial bodies. Second, mass shadow is explained as influence of gravity in hyperspace that pulls objects from hyperspace. Interdictors use mass shadow generators to pull objects from hyperspace or prevent them going there in first place. But you cannot crash in object from realspace while you are still in hyperspace.

Comment: @rs.29, course you add the source to that info on interdictors? I do not doubt you are right one second, I just wanted your answer to have more concrete references.

Comment: @rs.29 This [page on interdictors](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Interdictor-class_Star_Destroyer/Canon) says the mass shadow doesn't "pull" the ship from hyperspace. Instead the ship's hyperdrive notices the well and intentionally come back to normal space to prevent collision(which makes a lot of sense). if someone were to deactivate such a countermeasure, the ship would indeed crash into the mass shadow, and then we don't know what would happen(Though episode 8 presents a good guess.)

Comment: @Althis Wrong, page says explicitly " Interdictor-class possessed four spherical gravity well projectors on its sharp-bowed hull. The projectors contained equipment to pull a number of ships out of hyperspace. "  Also "One hemispherical projector was more than enough to pull a ship from hyperspace, while the others could be used to block possible hyperspace routes for escape" .

Comment: @JRE: Indeed, [*"The Rouge One"*](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/news/index.cfm) is something else entirely... :-D

Comment: @Althis And page for interdiction field says "An interdiction field was an artificial gravity well capable of disabling hyperspace maneuvers. Any starship stuck in the middle of an interdiction field became unable to jump into hyperspace. Inversely, such a field could yank a ship out of hyperspace, pulling it out abruptly into normal space." . Therefore, it tah has nothing to do with ship systems, it is simply artificially made gravity field http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Interdiction_field

Comment: It's plot hole the size of a *Mega*-class Star Dreadnought.

Comment: @Null - Star Wars didn't really seem to *have* locally faster than light travel. You can come out of hyperspace near an object with some decent speed and ram it, but not with enough energy to make this a useful strategy (usually).

Comment: Since the purpose of Rogue One was to fill a plot hole, this provide a rationale for another film to fill *this* plot hole.

Comment: @EvilSnack I would disagree. Rogue One explained events before Episode IV, but Episode IV by itself didn't have large plot holes. It was simple story of princess, villain and rescue party . In fact Rogue One created certain discrepancies, but that is another matter.

Answer (score 14):

At the beginning of the evacuation, the plan is to jump to lightspeed. Everyone believed they could not be tracked through lightspeed, so that was the end of it. No one had to sacrifice a big ship (remember how angry they were at Poe for murdering all their bombers).

The First Order then unveils its lightspeed-tracking tech, and re-engages the Resistance. The good guys have to scramble to figure out what to do next, and barely have time to get out of range of the First Order before they're all destroyed. If anyone had jumped to lightspeed in a suicide mission here, they might have destroyed both the First Order and the Resistance; everyone was just too close together, and too disorganized.

After they get out of range, the option to lightspeed-ram the First Order is still off the table, *because the First Order shoots them down*. The first two abandoned ships only have a matter of seconds after running out of fuel before they go up in flames, it's likely they wouldn't have had time to turn all the way around and engage their hyperdrive. The only reason the cruiser gets a chance to make the jump is because the First Order (was stupid enough to let them?) was preoccupied with shooting down the transport ships.

So, in summary, what the Resistance needed to pull off this maneuver was distance and time. Neither of which they had any to spare for the majority of the film.

Now, as for why no one ever invented hyperspace missiles, that's something I can't answer.

Comment: Spot on. Nobody could turn around due to the constant fire. Note how slowly Holdo's ship executed its turn.

Comment: "the First Order was stupid enough to let them?" Yes. General Hux seems to be a pretty terrible tactician.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good answer, after all, the "they wouldn't have time to turn the ship around" is pointless once you consider that their shields managed to take First Order fire for *days* and being depleted was never even considered. Turn that thing around, put all the power to side shields, then front shields and ram the damn thing at the speed of light!

Comment: They were able to take the constant fire because they moved out of "effective range".  The First Order only kept up the barrage to force them to keep moving and exhaust their fuel supplies.

Comment: You seem to be interpreting "doing it earlier" in OPs question as "earlier in the film", but the more interesting interpretation is, "Why hasn't this maneuver ever been used before?" I think _that_ is what is being asked here, which you admit you can't answer at all. :(

Answer (score 14):

Only to follow up @rs.29's correct but not elaborate answer, **this is a huge plot hole that will be affecting the rest of star wars merchandise**.

My start point would be the hyperspace definition from the [databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/hyperdrive):

> Hyperdrives allow starships to travel faster than the speed of light, crossing space through the alternate dimension of hyperspace. Large objects in normal space cast “mass shadows” in hyperspace, so hyperspace jumps must be precisely calculated to avoid collisions

Raddus, named after Admiral Raddus, the hero of battle of Scarif, is an MC85 Star Cruiser. The length is specified as 3,438.37 [meters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Raddus_(MC85_Star_Cruiser)). I could not obtain any mass evidence so hereby I assume the length is directly correlated by weight.

This indeed may be the largest cruiser employed by the resistance, however the resistance did have large cruisers before. MC80s are of 1200 meters and MC75 are of 1,204.44 [meters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/MC75_cruiser). These are massive ships relative to Millenium Falcon, a small ship that we know to be capable of jumping to the hyperspace. Rebellion indeed had massive ships, yet we do not see ramming at light speed as a strategy used with these ships.

The empire and the separatists used even bigger ships and they did not consider this strategy not once. For example, ramming of Malevolence, a ship even larger than MC85, to Coruscant could have been a perfect strategy. As long as it holds its deflector shields up, it could last enough to jump to the hyperspace as well, as we have seen MC85 jumping to the hyperspace, but it was not considered.

Using the answer by @DVK-on-Ahch-To [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68754/why-do-calculations-need-to-be-made-before-jumping-into-hyperspace), we know that massive objects can pull you of from hyperspace. The best directly in universe example is the blocking of the fleet of Admiral Raddus by Darth Vader while they were trying to retreat after battle of Scarif. If jumping to hyperspace was an allowed maneuver in close proximity to other massive and not aligned cruisers, we would expect MC75 of rebel alliance to ram into Devastator, the flagship of Darth Vader.

Apparently, from Hux's sudden fear when he ordered units to fire on MC85, the fact that jumping to the hyperspace might damage the vessels on its path is well known. Hence, it should not be the first time we witness such a thing, but to the best of my knowledge, there was no similar strategy in the whole Star Wars universe.

We do see an interesting hyperdrive jump in [S01E13 of clone wars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LX6-5yQ--yk), where an uncalculated hyperspace jump caused Anakin and Ahsoka to get lost. They detach immediately from the cruiser, however their reason of detachment is not clarified. Being a very small vessel, Anakin's ship should not cast a "mass shadow" stated in the [databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/hyperdrive). Anakin and Ahsoka getting lost after the uncalculated jump supports the idea that hyperspace jump calculations are mostly done to determine the exit point from the hyperspace.

In short, this move by Vice Admiral Holdo is unprecedented in the Star Wars universe and it would be a plot hole in the upcoming battles.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70433/discussion-on-answer-by-c-koca-why-was-thismanoeuvre-not-used-earlier).

Comment: Given what happens when "jumping to hyperspace...in close proximity to other massive and not aligned cruisers", it's perfectly obvious why the rebellion didn't do it above Scarif: they didn't want to blow up everything in sight, themselves included.

Comment: @Martha I strongly disagree. Adm. Raddus gives clear orders to prepare to jump to hyperspace and four seconds later by movie time Vader fleet arrives and prevents the hyperspace jump. There is no indication whatsoever that this was either automated by the hyperdrive generators or a decision change by Adm. Raddus. Even if that is the case, there is no good reason for rebel fleet not to jump to hyperspace after plans are forwarded to Leia. They could have scuttled half of Vader's fleet if this was physically possible.

Comment: @C.Koca: Could have scuttled half of Vader's fleet... and committed mass suicide in the process.

Comment: @Martha Were there any survivors from Adm. Raddus's ship anyway? So taking away half the Vader's fleet with them seems more profitable. Besides, these are all our conjecture. So far, what we know is their hyperspace jump was interrupted by Vader's fleet, as it should have happened with Holdo's ship.

Comment: First, I would like to remind you that "mass shadows" don't pull ships from hyperspace. They are pulled as a safety measure coded into their hyperdrives, but that could be disabled. Then I would like to remind everyone that the supremacy is 60 kilometers wide and one of the largest ships we've seen to date, probably enough to cast a mass shadow. Finally, if my theory is correct(which again I reiterate that there is no evidence that proves or disproves it), an object would need to be of comparative size for the collision to have any effect on the realspace object.

Comment: @Althis "They are pulled as a safety measure coded into their hyperdrives" source? Even if it is correct, why didn't Raddus disable it as well? What was it that Holdo can pull off single handedly but Raddus cannot do it with an intact ship and full crew? Also, my first comment to Martha answers some part of your theory as well. Your theory, like the theories of all others, is a hopeless attempt to merge the Disney canon with the rest of the SW canon.

Comment: @Althis Imterdictors are mobile mass shadow generators that can pull ships from hyperspace as well as limit their access to it. However we also see the Star Destroyers behind Snoke's ship destroyed in a similar way and they are clearly a lot smaller, so I'm not sure the size is as important.

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR: Holdo hit a one in a million chance of this actually working, by a combination of incredible skill, luck and poor tactics of the first order.**

As far as I have understood the movies, the following rules seem to govern hyperspace travel in Star Wars:

1. Ships in Star Wars never fly with a relevant fraction of light speed, sub-light travel seems to be quite slow.
2. Going to hyperspace is a shift to the hyperspace dimension, where ships still travel with normal speed, but hyperspace routes can connect two points in real space with a short cut. So a ship flying through hyper space arrives faster than light travelling the normal path through real space.
3. Ships coming out of hyperspace travel with normal sublight speed and just appear into realspace.
4. Big objects like asteroid or big parts of capital ships can easily break through normal Star Destroyer shields and inflict devastating damage.
5. Big objects cast mass shadows into hyperspace, which are very dangerous for hyperspace traveling ships, so they drop out of hyperspace when the scanners detect an unexpected mass shadow.

#### My interpretation of the depicted events:

Holdos jump into hyperspace crossed the mass shadow of Snokes giant ship and she disabled the safety system, which would have dropped her out of hyperspace before colliding with the mass shadow. - The collision with the mass shadow ripped her ship apart and these parts dropped out of hyperspace (because the hyperdrive of course failed when her ship was destroyed). The parts of her ship collided with the fleet of the first order with considerable speed, since they were still flying with maximum speed towards holdos ship.

Some parts dropped out of hyperspace inside of shields, some shields may not have been fully powered up and some parts may have been highly explosive (generator, engine, weapon systems...) or simply big enough to create massive damage on impact.

Overall the attack may have only been so effective, because the first order ships flew too close together and were caught by surprise, didn't have their shields fully operational and no interdictor at hand. And there also seems to be a lot of luck and intuition involved, so that the ship wasn't ripped apart too early or thrown off course.

*So maybe there is only a 1% chance to even find a hyperspace route and get the timing perfectly right, so ones ship exactly drops out of hyperspace where the target is. If one doesn't get this right all the scattered parts will just appear behind the enemy or randomly fly in the wrong direction. And even if one hits the timing and course perfectly right one has to be lucky to hit sensitive/lowly shielded parts of the enemy, or hit the one in a million chance of an explosive part of the suicide ship appearing inside of a shield*

Comment: Even if this is the case, I strap a hyperspace engine to an bunch of asteroids, turn off the safeties, jump. Even if you talk about deflector shields, I get enough asteroids and enough kinetic energy, I'm going to beat the shields.

Comment: @ifly you are right, you would still have to be good on direction and timing to score a good hit. AND in Canon a hyperdrive is the vastly most expensive part of a ship, furthermore one with the power and reach to carry several asteroids, so it would not be cheap. Plus you would have to hit your enemy, before they just shoot your vessel down, so you need time to bring it into position and a score of tie fighters could vaporize it with a single hit

Comment: Or a turbo laser could probably splatter an asteroid when reading a hyperdrive signature on it, before the computations for the jump would be complete.

Comment: And the "one in a million chance" is the reason confirmed in *Rise of Skywalker*.

Comment: @Falco "Ships coming out of hyperspace travel with normal sublight speed and just appear into realspace." - this contradicts very basic Special Relativity.  There is no favoured frame of reference. The only reason why admiral's Holdo's fleet can be called to have a "high speed" is that it moves fast relative to other celestial objects, space dust etc..

Comment: @Falco "because the first order ships flew too close together and were caught by surprise, didn't have their shields fully operational and no interdictor at hand"  - this means that Kamikadze attack should be pretty useful if enemy is ambushed by a space rock suddenly  going hyperspace (rigged with a minimum equipment making it hyperspace-capable).

Answer (score 3):

Without reconning, I think that this a major plot problem ... I almost jumped out of my seat when it happened. The FTL projectile thing has been left out of a lot of classic sci-fi (including Lucas' universe) because it so completely alters the nature of war. Some other answers discuss the size of the space ship and the shadow it casts in realspace, but I would remind readers that *any* object approaching the speed of light in realspace is approaching infinite mass (or more if FTL?), so the size of the ship doesn't really matter any more.

m = m0/((1 - v2/c2))1/2

So ... even if the spaceship/projectile is fractionally in realspace and fractionally in hyperspace at the initial instant of the jump to lightspeed, a fraction of a near-infinite mass is ... also near infinite.

I think that authors will need to develop an in-universe "fix" to this problem before the next movie ... like the gravity-well weapon or something else to keep light-speed objects from being used as projectiles. Of course, there will be the separate problem of slowing down something with literally infinite kinetic energy with a technology with presumably finite energy, but maybe that can be addressed also.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If this works, and hyperdrives can be installed on small ships as we see (on fighters and small freighters) then missile-like ships with just a bunch of rock or metal, a hyperdrive and a droid pilot would be the bane of big ships, able to do devastating damage for a minuscule fraction of the cost/resources/life.

Answer (score 3):

### New thought: the Supremacy ships *also* jumped to lightspeed, and the collision happened in hyperspace

Borrowing a little bit from @McIntyre's line of logic, this is clearly the first time that 1) ships have been trackable through lightspeed and 2) this kind of collision occurs. It's rather intuitive that the two are related somehow.

What I propose, with zero evidence for, is that the Supremacy ships were *automatically* tracking the Raddus. No need for captains here, but you do need a very rapid response as soon as the Raddus jumps - perfect for the ship's computers to handle. As soon as the new tracking software detects that the ship has gone FTL, it takes the Supremacy ships FTL as well.

Thus, **the collision itself happens in hyperspace**, not in regular space. This resolves the "hyperspace doesn't collide with real space" problem, as well as demonstrating why this tactic wasn't used on the Death Star or similar: those targets weren't in hyperspace, so they couldn't have been attacked in this way. This *also* explains the rather odd and trippy lighting of the scene. Rather than being a special effects kind of choice, it's simply how a collision in hyperspace should look. You can also see that all nearby planets and stars are no longer visible behind the Supremacy ships- exactly what we'd expect to see if the camera was in hyperspace, but not moving.

The looks of horror on the Supremacy leader's faces were caused by the realization that the tracking program would result in exactly this kind of response. They realized too late that they were going to jump into hyperspace at the same time the Raddus blasted through it.

Comment: But why was the *Supremacy* still there?

Comment: @Möoz Presumably, when the hyperspace drive is destroyed, the ships drop back out of hyperspace. Perhaps not *instananeously*, but any time delay is significant when we're looking at FTL speeds

Comment: Creative, but the lines "Sir, the Resistance cruiser's preparing to jump to lightspeed."/ "It's empty. They're just trying to pull our attention away. Pathetic. Keep your fire on the transports." indicates they had no worry of being pulled away from firing on the transports if Holdo jumped.

Comment: This is simply incorrect. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Ok well in regards to using hyperspace as a weapon it’s not usable however there are two points were it could be used. Both entering and exiting hyperspace. At both point the ship hasn’t entered or has left hyperspace and is still at a significant fraction of the Speed of light. At this speed the results would be devastating. That said as to why it isn’t used as a tactic? Well space is a very big place and this type of tactic would be a crap shoot in fact it you would be more likely than not to miss your target. Further the rebel alliance and the Resitance are working with limit resources and are desperate but not suicidal. Even throwing junky ships at them would be resource prohibitive.

Comment: So the most likely result should have been that the admiral missed and just jumped her way someplace random, but only by complete blind luck it worked this time? So really it was a really dumb idea that by all rights should have failed but happened to work, and the drama and alarm around it was inappropriate? And if this can work, given the massive damage done when it does, why not make many robotic suicide missile-ships?

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking that this may be the first case in Star Wars canon where a ship accelerated to lightspeed without entering hyperspace.

It's possible that one of these things occurred:

1. Snoke's ship was massive enough on it's own that it functioned as an Interdictor, casting a mass shadow large enough to prevent ships from entering hyperspace.
2. Snoke's ship actually had an interdictor device on board and was actively using it.
3. Holdo intentionally programmed her jump to avoid going to hyperspace until after she passed Snoke's ship, and was simply accelerating to lightspeed, but had not quite achieved it at the time of collision (.99C)

Thus, we had an actual physical collision of two massive objects, one of which was travelling at a significant portion of C.

I don't have mass figures, but judging by the size of Snoke's ship and the assumed speed of the Raddus, I'd guess that the destruction we saw on screen was significantly less than what normal physics would expect. I would theorize that Holdo did some math wizardry in her calculations to hold the kinetic energy of the collision down to a level where she didn't destroy every object in the entire star system, including the planet.

Comment: All those who think this answer is unrealistic, please read this: https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

Comment: 1/2) Actually, the events of the movie aren't consistent with a relativistic event. Use this calculator [http://www.stardestroyer.net/Resources/Calculators/NuclearExplosions.html] to estimate the yield needed to engulf Snoke's ship (~40gtns), then use this calculator [http://www.unitconversion.org/energy/joules-to-gigatons-conversion.html] to convert to joules (1.7e20), and this calculator [http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/releng.html] to determine the speed needed for the Raddus (~6e10 kg) to generate that force (.00025c or 270000 kph).

Comment: 2/2) That's very fast, but not any appreciable fraction of c, and what we see instead is a very localized straight-line damage, not an engulfing blast.  I am going to guess that what we're seeing is a hyperspace wake effect, in which portions of the Supremacy are stripped away into hyperspace along with Raddus.  This theory also allows for Holdo and the Raddus to have survived.

Comment: 3/2) Also, I'm estimating the mass of the Supremacy at 1.6e14 kg, which would give it a gravitation about 14 millionths of Earth's.  I'm not sure if that's large enough to pull a ship out of hyperspace, but I bet not.  The Supremacy is about 3000x larger than Raddus.

Answer (score 2):

(Reasoning-based, not in-universe canon based)

**In exercising their own unprecedented tactic to create a never-before-seen, unique situation, the First Order opened themselves up to another.**

It all comes down to the hyperspace tracking and the First Order's tactics due to it (which you could put down to hubris). Without it:

1. hyperspace escape is possible (no **need** for Holdo Manoeuvre);
2. if interdicted, no jump possible anyway (no **chance** of Holdo Manoeuvre);
3. the approaching force with weapons superiority would not take a slow and patient 'wait until they're out of fuel' approach, (no **chance** of Holdo Manoeuvre)

3 is the most important. The overconfidence and complacency in letting the prey bleed and weaken is exactly what left the First Order vulnerable to the Holdo Manoeuvre. They could have:

- held back and waited until fuel was gone, then pounced;
- relaunched smaller faster craft to take out the Resistance's engines
- called in reinforcements further along the Resistance's trajectory
- jumped away and jumped back;
- jumped away, waited for the Resistance to jump, tracked them again and hit them hard upon jumping to them.

They did none of these things, instead choosing to patiently toy with them, because of their overconfidence in their newly available tactic.

**So how does this explain why the Holdo Manoeuvre was never used before?**

This situation never **happened** before. There was never any **reason** to consider this tactic. Keep in mind, that despite centuries of hyperspace travel, the First Order's hyperspace tracking technology had apparently never been used, or been known to. It's a brand new tactical challenge.

This whole conundrum is only going for 18 hours. We've got people who are very accustomed to the concept of hyperspace travel and the normal limitations of it. In the face of a brand new, game-changing technology, people simply aren't likely to think up a brand new way of doing things straight away. It's going to take time or necessity to come up with something like the Holdo Manoeuvre (which is what happened, and to be fair, it was pretty quick).

Also, keep in mind that Hux appeared to realise what was happening at the last minute. This was a unique situation. The Holdo Manoeuvre, once famous, is unlikely to ever be quite so effective again.

*Note:* You may ask, why hadn't it been used before in a different situation? For example, to destroy the original Death Star, why not aim a Mon Calamari cruiser and go to hyperspace? Well for a start it's risky. Holdo had nothing to lose, and her manoeuvre wasn't essential for the plan (which was simply to make the First Order think the cruiser was still crewed, creep up on it and destroy it). If it had failed, the original plan would still be fulfilled. If the Holdo Manoeuvre were tried on the Death Star or similar target, and failed, they'd have played their hand and be doomed.

**TL;DR**

It was a response to a new tactic, and those take time. Really, under 18 hours is pretty good.

Comment: i would also add that the fleet being out of sb-space fuel was a critical factor. In a normal engagement, there would be no need for such a risky maneuver when a normal ramming would likely achieve the same result. Thanks to the situation, there simply would not have been enough fuel left to first cancel out the forward momentum and then accelerate to ramming speed. The only way to get from point A to point B would be a risky hyperspace jump.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it was caused by an interaction with the hyperspace tracking device, which works in an unspecified, unique manner.

Answer (score 1):

The Rebel's plan was to sneak away to their hidden base. It failed because their small transport ships were spotted and the First Order began firing on them.

Up until that point the larger ships were being used to fool the First Order into thinking that they were about to destroy the remaining rebels. The Rebels were also hoping for assistance from their allies as another means of escape.

Given that the light-speed ramming attack didn't stop the First Order's pursuit anyway (it just temporarily halted their attack) it just didn't make sense to do it.

Additionally, when the First Order saw what was being planned they began pounding the ram ship with every available weapon. While not explicitly stated that ship would have required very good shielding to survive long enough, and it's not clear if the other ships had it.

Answer (score 1):

This is (somewhat) addressed in *The Rise of Skywalker*.

> A Resistance character suggests using "the Holdo maneuver" against the First Order, but another one dismisses the idea, saying it's a "million to one shot".

It's not addressed further, but we can surmise that it's not guaranteed to work, so can't be relied upon as a usual tactic.

The Visual Dictionary gives further detail, in a section about *The Last Jedi*:

> Vice Admiral Holdo perfectly times a devastating point-blank hyperspace jump so that her massive warship, the three-kilometer long *Raddus*, intersects the mass of the *Supremacy* at lightspeed before her ship fully enters hyperspace. The resulting collision cuts the *Supremacy* in half.
>
> (*Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary*, page 28)

So it seems that the tricky part of the maneuver is timing it just right: the piloted ship has to be traveling fast enough to cause damage, but can't have entered hyperspace yet. Since getting a ship in the right place at the right time while traveling at lightspeed would probably require very high levels of precision, this offers an explanation for the maneuver being difficult to pull off.

Comment: That's not "addressed", that's "handwaved away".

Comment: I'll always wonder if it got christened with this question or if it was already being called that.

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed in [*The Star Wars Book*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars_Book). In brief, you need a combination of three main factors; Firstly, you need **incredible skill on the part of the pilot in calculating the jump and timing precisely**, secondly, you need **incredible luck in not simply missing your target** and finally, **you need to be using a massive ship** (capital class) in order for the mass to be sufficient to overwhelm the normal shields and armour that ships deploy when they're moving through space.

> In battle, the most common use of hypertravel is to and from the
> battlefield, but **there are rare cases of lightspeed jumps being used
> offensively. Launching a ship at a target is a risky, suicidal
> strategy that some consider to be a result of luck as much as it is
> skill.** After Vice-Admiral Holdo uses the tactic to destroy the First
> Order’s Star Dreadnought Supremacy, it becomes known as the “Holdo
> Maneuver.”

and

> **For such a maneuver to work, the jumping craft must be sizable,** making
> it a very expensive tactic. The Raddus is over three kilometers (two
> miles) in length. **The Raddus’ jump distance must intersect its target
> while it is entering lightspeed, when jump collisions are most likely.
> This makes it a point-blank maneuver.**