# How feasible is a hyperdrive-based weapon? (Star Wars 8 spoiler)

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, weapon

After the battle in The Last Jedi when the ship activated its hyperdrive and tore through the Star Destroyer, I immediately began wondering why weapons weren't being made that utilized hyperdrives to push something really fast to be used as a projectile. What I'm wondering is how much it would cost to develop a weapon like this compared to other weapons in the Star Wars universe, and why such a weapon had not been created hundreds of years ago.

Comment: You appear to have edited and marked to reopen. I'm curious how/why you feel that the dupe doesn't answer this question.

Comment: Also see: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115994/are-there-any-hyper-drive-based-star-wars-weapons

Comment: this question is about why a weapon like this hadn't been developed hundreds of years earlier, not why the maneuver wasn't done earlier in the movie by other dead ships